# Can you integrate opencv SIFT with a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, sift

I am trying to create a CNN, but using the SIFT algorithm instead of any pooling layers.
Problem is I can't seem to find any Python implementation of the algorithm in Tensorflow or PyTorch. The only implementation I have seen of it is with opencv.

Is it possible to use the opencv SIFT implementation as a layer in a Tensorflow CNN Model?
If so, how would you go about creating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is an interesting idea, I believe it has numerous issues that make it highly impracticable to impossible.

Layers of a network have to be differentiable with regards to their input to allow any gradients to be calculated, which are then used to update the weights.
While I think it might be possible to write a fully differentiable sift implementation, this alone will be impractical.

Further SIFT does not have a constant number of outputs and takes a long time to compute, which would slow down the training a lot.

The only practical way to use SIFT with neural networks would be to first run SIFT and then use the top N detected keypoints as input for the first layer. However, I'm not sure this would be successful.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was fearing would make it not a workable solution.
I wanted to investigate this approach, since it has already been done on some academic papers. Still, none of those papers link to a github page or any code at all, therefore I still can't implement SIFT with either TF or Torch

Comment: @gilbertocunha could you maybe link one of these papers? I can't find something like that right now.

Comment: Sure thing, I have been taking a look at these two:
1 - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.00197.pdf
2 - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.02833.pdf

Comment: Oh interesting. Then I think you should be able to follow the normal way of writing custom layers for tensorflow/keras, which you can find here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models .  Maybe this github code can help you, which implements sift in Keras, but not as a layer. https://github.com/ducha-aiki/keras-sift/blob/master/keras_sift.py

Comment: thank you! It might prove useful!
Meanwhile, after a little more searching, I also found this github code for a pytorch implementation of SIFT. If you are interested: https://github.com/ducha-aiki/pytorch-sift .   
I still havent tested it, though. Thanks for the help!